# MongoDB - Average fields values over documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with this schema:

```
{
    "fields":
        {
            "field1": [
                {"name": "abc", "value": 2},
                {"name": "bcd", "value": 4},
                {"name": "cde", "value": 6}
            ],
            "field2": [
                {"name": "dec", "value": 3},
                {"name": "das", "value": 8},
                {"name": "pam", "value": 10}
            ]
        }
},
{
    "fields":
        {
            "field1": [
                {"name": "abc", "value": 7},
                {"name": "cde", "value": 12}
            ],
            "field2": [
                {"name": "dec", "value": 3},
                {"name": "das", "value": 8},
                {"name": "pam", "value": 10}
            ]
        }
}
```

What I'm trying to obtain is e.g. the average values of all members of 'field1', evaluating 0 if a member exist in a document but not in another (like 'bcd').

So in this example I should get:

```
{
    '_id': 'abc',
    'avg': 4.5
},
{
    '_id': 'bcd',
    'avg': 2
},
{
    '_id': 'cde',
    'avg': 9
}
```

I wrote this aggregation query but I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with it:

```
db.statuses.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$fields.field1'
    },
    {
        $group: { 
            _id: '$fields.field1.name', 
            avg: { 
                $avg: '$fields.field1.value'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            avg: -1
        }
    }
])
```

I think I should add a step before the average calculation in which I have to build an array of all values for each name (0 if the name does not exist in a document), and then evaluate the average on these arrays. Am I right?

How could I do this?

Comment: Can you post valid documents, no `...`. trust me no one have time to figure out what's wrong with data.